# status 0 from the server in http post method

Tags: angular, api, server, nest

I am trying to test my project in the login stage with an API that can respond with access_token and refresh_token so I tested the API with the Postman platform then gets successes:

[image]

and then get testing this with my Angular project with these statements:

```
 userLogin(userPayload): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", userPayload)
            .pipe(
                map((value: any) => { 
                    if (value) {
                        localStorage.setItem("access_token", value.access_token);
                        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", value.refresh_token);
                        const decryptedUser = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(value.access_token);
                        console.log(decryptedUser);
                        const data = {
                            access_token: value.access_token,
                            refresh_token: value.refresh_token,
                            username: decryptedUser.username,
                            userid: decryptedUser.sub,
                            tokenExpiration: decryptedUser.user
                        };
                        this.userInfo.next(data);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                    
                })
            );
    }
```

and this is [my API](https://github.com/Naveen512/NestJS-Jwt-Auth-Mock_API#support).

and when I am serving my project I get this error I don't know why doesn't request right:

[image]

Comment: Have you passed the headers in api request from angular side?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with below code?

```
userLogin(userPayload): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.http.post("http://localhost:3000/auth/login", userPayload, {headers : new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })})
            .pipe(
                map((value: any) => { 
                    if (value) {
                        localStorage.setItem("access_token", value.access_token);
                        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", value.refresh_token);
                        const decryptedUser = this.jwtHelper.decodeToken(value.access_token);
                        console.log(decryptedUser);
                        const data = {
                            access_token: value.access_token,
                            refresh_token: value.refresh_token,
                            username: decryptedUser.username,
                            userid: decryptedUser.sub,
                            tokenExpiration: decryptedUser.user
                        };
                        this.userInfo.next(data);
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false;
                    
                })
            );
}
```